# JQuery and Submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I need your help. I created this simple script. My goal is to update my database with the text inside the textarea of this form. The problem is that the script works only the second time i press the submit button. For some unknown reason (at least for me) it doesn't work the first time.. May you help me, please?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form_dove").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
        $("#click_dove").click(function(){
           testo = $("#textarea_dove_2").val();
           alert(testo);
           data = 'testo='+testo;
                $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"php/update_dove.php",
                        data: data,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                        $('#textarea_dove_2').val(html);
                        alert('Aggiornato!');
                         }
                       });
                    });
                  });
                });
       </script>

 <form name="form_dove" method="post" id="form_dove">
 <div id="textarea_dove">
 <textarea rows="17" cols="90" name="textarea_dove_2"                   id="textarea_dove_2" >
<?php echo("$testo_dove"); ?>
</textarea> 
</div>
<div id="form_submit_dove">
<input type="submit" value="SALVA E AGGIORNA" id="click_dove">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the ajax call is done in the button click handler, but the button click handler is registered in the form submit handler, so only after the first form submit(triggered by the submit button click) the click event handler which is doing the ajax call will get registered.

Solution: You don't need the click event handler, move the ajax call to the submit event handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form_dove").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        testo = $("#textarea_dove_2").val();
        alert(testo);
        data = 'testo=' + testo;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/update_dove.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#textarea_dove_2').val(html);
                alert('Aggiornato!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info, as soon as I get home I'll try the codes :-)

Comment: ok both the script works but I have another problem..
the php script is executed but the text passed to the php scrip is the original one and not what i typed before pressing the submit button
To better understand (sorry for my english), when i load the page inside the textarea there is written: "hello". Then I edited the textarea and I write: "hello 123". When i press the submit button, the scripts pass the first string and not the second one..

Comment: I did a little research using Google I discovered that the problem may be TinyMCE Editor. Yes I am using it, sorry to not mention it before but I didn't know it could be the nature of my problem.. I am using the version 4.1.7 of TinyMCE Editor.. may you please help me?
Thanks for the patience and the help, really really appreciated!
Davide,

Comment: @P.Davide try to call `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` just before `testo = $("#textarea_dove_2").val();`

Answer (score 1):

The `$("#click_dove").click` is inside the submit.

This means the click becomes active only after the form is submitted. The code is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two functions here. The $("#form_dove").submit function gets called when the form is submitted and the $("#click_dove").click function is invoked when the button is clicked.

Because you put the definition of the click function inside the submit function, the click function was not declared (ie didn't exist) until the form was submitted (ie. the first time you clicked the button). Then the second time the button was pressed, the click function did your ajax stuff.

In this case, it's most straightforward just do the processing you want in the submit function - it's what you want to happen when the form is submitted. Use the click function if you need to do some checking to see if the form has been filled in properly before submitting it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form_dove").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      testo = $("#textarea_dove_2").val();
      alert(testo);
      data = 'testo='+testo;
      $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"php/update_dove.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $('#textarea_dove_2').val(html);
                    alert('Aggiornato!');
                 }
       });
    });
    $("#click_dove").click(function(){
      //put some validation in here if you want
    });
});
</script>
```